# Angular do not see the selector of my component

Tags: javascript, angular

I have created component (slider) and I cant see him in another file (main-page).

> If 'app-slider' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part
> of this module.

**slider.component.ts**  where my `app-slider` selector

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-slider',
  templateUrl: './slider.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./slider.component.scss']
})
export class SliderComponent implements OnInit {
```

**components.module.ts** the module where I `declatations/export` my  `SliderComponent`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { SliderComponent } from './slider/slider.component';

import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';

    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        SharedModule.forRoot()
      ],
      declarations: [SliderComponent],
      exports: [SliderComponent]
    
    })
    export class ComponentsModule { }
```

**main-page.component.html** where I use `<app-slider></app-slider>`

```
<div class="content">
    <section class="main">
        <div class="container">
            <app-slider></app-slider>
            ....
```

**PagesModule** where my `MainPageComponent`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { SharedModule } from '../../shared/shared.module';

import { MainPageComponent } from './main-page/main-page.component';




@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedModule.forRoot()
  ],
  declarations: [MainPageComponent],

})
export class PagesModule { }
```

**App.module.ts** with both modules

```
import { ComponentsModule } from './components/components.module';
import { PagesModule } from './routes/pages/pages.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ComponentsModule,
    PagesModule,
...
```

**UPD 1**
I have removed `ComponentsModule` and `PagesModule` from `App.modules` and Imported `ComponentsModule` in `PagesModule` but problem is the same. Please check the [link](https://prnt.sc/v2aeeb)

**PagesModule**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { SharedModule } from '../../shared/shared.module';

import { ComponentsModule } from '../../components/components.module';
import { MainPageComponent } from './main-page/main-page.component';


    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        ComponentsModule,
        SharedModule.forRoot()
      ],
      declarations: [MainPageComponent],
    
    })
    export class PagesModule { }
```

**App.module.ts** after update

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { RoutesModule } from './routes/routes.module';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
import { LayoutModule } from './layout/layout.module';
import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    LayoutModule,
    RoutesModule,
    SharedModule.forRoot(),
    CoreModule,
    BrowserModule,

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `ComponentsModule` should not be imported at the root module of your application (`AppModule`) but in the modules that actually use it. In your case, `PagesModule` should import  `ComponentsModule`.

Only services are made available to the whole app when declared in a module that is imported in `AppModule` (via injectors mechanism).

Comment: thanks , if I use <app-layout> in app.component.html then I can put LayoutModule into the App.modules.ts , right ?

Comment: Of course you can use a component in its own module

Comment: I have updated the file but problem is the same :-( . UPD 1 in my question

Comment: Did you restart `ng serve`?

Comment: yes , it is confusing for me as <app-layout> in App.component.html  is ok as module was imported to App.module. Same thing for PagesModule is not working. I feel that I have missed something

Comment: should I import PagesModule somewhere ? I do not import it anywhere

Comment: The problem was that I didnt import PagesModule  in App.modules.ts. When I imported the one , the problem has gone